# Saving all loop results

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

Good morning,

I think my question must be quite simple but I don't find how to do it. I have a loop and I want to 'save' the results. The problem is with the code I only can save the 'last' column, not all. Here's the code:

```
b = xlsread('Data.xls', 'Sheet1'); %here I'm reading the excel data
d= size(b); % the size of the input table is 8 x 16 columns.
cols= d(:,2); 
Results=[]

for a=b(:,2:cols)

     n= 2;
     m2 = ar(a,n);
    K=6;
    hf2=forecast(m2,a,K); 

 for a=b(:,2:cols) % here I try to save the results but it only save the 'last column', not all the columns. 
     Results=[forecast(m2,a,K)]
  end
end
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the second loop, where you are saving the output. `Results` is replaced in each iteration with the new output. You should preallocate `Results` to its final size before the loop and fill it column by column in the loop. Having two loops also does not make sense. Here I got rid of some extra variables and tried to make your code neat:

```
b = xlsread('Data.xls', 'Sheet1');
[~, cols] = size(b);
n = 2;
K = 6;
Results = zeros(K, cols - 1);
for ii = 2:cols
    a = b(:, ii);
    Results(: , ii) = forecast(ar(a, n), a, K);
end
```